# How to specify different throughput values for different dispatchers in Akka?

Tags: configuration, akka

My Akka Actor System has a number of different dispatchers. Example would be something like the following in my `application.conf` file...

```
market-dispatcher {
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  type = PinnedDispatcher
  thread-pool-executor.allow-core-timeout=off
}
```

Now I would like to configure my dispatchers even further by specifying a value for the throughput. I have tried the obvious solution...

```
market-dispatcher {
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  type = PinnedDispatcher
  thread-pool-executor.allow-core-timeout=off
  throughput = 1000
}
```

...but I did not notice any obvious different in system performance. Is it possible to configure throughput separately for individual dispatchers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can configure the throughput per dispatcher. But regarding your example, for a PinnedDispatcher, the throughput setting is ignored. From the docs:

> Throughput defines the maximum number of messages to be processed per
>   actor before the thread jumps to the next actor.

But then, PinnedDispatcher

> dedicates a unique thread for each actor

so the thread will never jump to another actor.

As it's difficult to make sense of the combination of PinnedDispatcher and setting throughput, the throughput setting is ignored in this case.

Regarding your comment:

> This means at most 8 < 10 threads can make progress at any point in
>   time and thus, at any point in time, 2 of the actors using the
>   PinnedDispatcher will have idle threads.

I don't think I understand your example. In my understanding, the thread being idle would mean the actor has no messages to process, not there is no CPU core to run on. All 10 could be runnable, or idle, independent of the number of cores.

> I am trying to understand how to control the point at which an actor
>   using a PinnedDispatcher stops making progress and is forced to idle
>   in this case.

You mean forced to give up the core? By using the PinnedDispatcher, you are saying you leave this decision to the OS scheduler. It seems you'd like to "yield" the thread explicitly after processing a number of messages. I think that's rather uncommon, and not something built into Akka. The "natural" yielding point would be after processing *throughput* number of messages, which would work on other kinds of dispatchers.
Why do you use a PinnedDispatcher in the first place?

Comment: Good point. However, suppose that I have a group of 10 actors using a `PinnedDispatcher` running on a machine with 4 (8) physical (logical) cores.  This means at most 8 < 10 threads can make progress at any point in time and thus, at any point in time, 2 of the actors using the `PinnedDispatcher` will have idle threads.  I am trying to understand how to control the point at which an actor using a `PinnedDispatcher` stops making progress and is forced to idle in this case.  Perhaps this represents a design flaw in the way I am configuring dispatchers?

Comment: I am building a large-scale market simulator using Scala and Akka.  The system consists of a large number (i.e., order of one million) `TradingActors` and much smaller number (i.e., order of one thousand) `MarketActors`. Orders of magnitudes given are upper bounds on the system I would like to build: I often run simulations with one or two markets and a few thousand traders. I felt it made sense to give my `MarketActors` dedicated threads as each `MarketActor` will have quite a lot of messages to process and I want my markets to have high throughput. Thus my use of the `PinnedDispatcher`.

Comment: I don't think you'll achieve higher throughput with PinnnedDispatchers, they are more useful to optimize for latency rather than throughput. Maybe http://letitcrash.com/post/20397701710/50-million-messages-per-second-on-a-single is interesting for you, too.

Comment: Perhaps I am using the wrong terminology.  Let me distinguish between software threads and hardware threads.  On my machine with 4 (8) physical (logical) corse only 8 hardware threads can make progress at any point in time.  As you point out there can be any number of software threads all of which may be runnable or idle. Whether a particular software thread is runnable or idle is dependent on whether or not there are messages left to process in the relevant actor's mailbox and is independent of the number of cores.